# form_hidden in codeigniter twig

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, ion-auth

how can I recreate this code in twig?

```
<?php echo form_hidden(array('id'=>$user->id)); ?>
```

That's what I did, but it does not work

```
{{ form_hidden(array('id'=>user.id)) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Form Open**

```
{{ form_open('controller/method') }}
```

**Hidden Fields**

```
{{ form_hidden('name',  value) }}
```

**Form Close**

```
{{ form_close() }}
```

**Set Value**

```
{{ set_value('name') }}
```